# Cannot use AllowedPattern in SSM doc schemaVersion: 2.2

Tags: aws-ssm

allowedPattern is mentioned in System Manager documentation as parameter value:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-doc-syntax.html

But I'm failing to add it to my existing doc:

`InvalidDocumentContent: Unknown property "AllowedPattern".`

```
schemaVersion: '2.2'
description: Cat file from temp
parameters:
  path:
    type: String
    description: path to file
    AllowedPattern: ^\/tmp\/ssm-...$
mainSteps:
- action: aws:runShellScript
  name: runShellScript
  inputs:
    timeoutSeconds: '30'
    runCommand:
    - if [ -f {{ path }} ]; then cat {{ path }}; else echo None; fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all places for AWS CFT. we use AllowedPattern but only in case of SSM custom document it is allowedPattern. Below should work for you

```
schemaVersion: '2.2'
description: Cat file from temp
parameters:
  path:
    type: String
    description: path to file
    allowedPattern: ^\/tmp\/ssm-...$
mainSteps:
  - action: aws:runShellScript
    name: runShellScript
    inputs:
      timeoutSeconds: '30'
      runCommand:
        - if [ -f {{ path }} ]; then cat {{ path }}; else echo None; fi
```